# Legens for line chart read from read.csv2 using R Base

Tags: r

I have the following variable:

```
res = read.csv2(text = "X-Years;Y-Halden;Y-Moss;Y-Sarpsborg
2020;31373;49273;56732
2030;32839;51918;59261
2040;34292;54535;61214
2050;35345;56632;62598")
```

I want to have the headlines only because I want to add them into a legen, like this:

```
legend("topleft", legend=c("Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"),
       col=c(1, 2, 3), lty = 1:2, cex=0.8)
```

Where Line 1 = Y-Halden, Line 2 = Y-Moss and Line 3=Y-Sarpsborg.

I tried this, but it only produces years:

```
res = read.csv2(text = "X-Years;Y-Halden;Y-Moss;Y-Sarpsborg
2020;31373;49273;56732
2030;32839;51918;59261
2040;34292;54535;61214
2050;35345;56632;62598")

headlines = res[ ,0:1]
headlines
```

> ### [1] 2020 2030 2040 2050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `names`:

```
headlines = names(res)
headlines

[1] "X.Years"     "Y.Halden"    "Y.Moss"      "Y.Sarpsborg"
```

If you want to get rid of `X.Years`:

```
headlines = names(res)[-1]
headlines

[1] "Y.Halden"    "Y.Moss"      "Y.Sarpsborg"
```

And now you can use `headlines` in your legend like so:

```
legend("topleft", legend = headlines,
       col=c(1, 2, 3), lty = 1:2, cex=0.8)
```